# FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY`

Tags: kotlin, build, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kapt, viewmodel-savedstate

i hope you can find my text cause i really confused with my project because the app can't installed in emulator. I wish your advice and guidance.
this the Logcat when running the app

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                                    Process: com.kirani.submee, PID: 20134
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CreationExtras must have a value by `SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY`
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateHandleSupport.createSavedStateHandle(SavedStateHandleSupport.kt:91)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.create(AbstractSavedStateViewModelFactory.java:89)
                                                                                                        at dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.HiltViewModelFactory.create(HiltViewModelFactory.java:114)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:187)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.kt:153)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:53)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelLazy.kt:35)
                                                                                                        at com.kirani.submee.fragments.loginRegister.RegisterFragment.getViewModel(RegisterFragment.kt:22)
                                                                                                        at com.kirani.submee.fragments.loginRegister.RegisterFragment.access$getViewModel(RegisterFragment.kt:18)
                                                                                                        at com.kirani.submee.fragments.loginRegister.RegisterFragment$onViewCreated$2.invokeSuspend(RegisterFragment.kt:48)
                                                                                                        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
                                                                                                        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.DispatchQueue.drainQueue(DispatchQueue.kt:75)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.DispatchQueue.resume(DispatchQueue.kt:54)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleController.observer$lambda-0(LifecycleController.kt:40)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleController.$r8$lambda$7XqClT_TFDHmqX3ARP07WvbP2Qg(Unknown Source:0)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleController$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onStateChanged(Unknown Source:4)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:360)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:271)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:313)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:151)
                                                                                                        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:134)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3167)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:588)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:279)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1424)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2968)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:2893)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3171)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:588)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:279)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:113)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1424)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2968)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:2893)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:274)
                                                                                                        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:359)
                                                                                                        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1543)
                                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8330)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3670)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
2023-09-09 21:14:38.845 20134-20134 AndroidRuntime          com.kirani.submee                    E      at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
                                                                                                        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2307)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
                                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
                                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
                                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
                                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
                                                                                                        Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@b7e6f51, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
```

RegisterViewModel.kt

```
package com.kirani.submee.viewmodel

import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import com.kirani.submee.data.User
import com.kirani.submee.util.Resource
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.MutableStateFlow
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import javax.inject.Inject

@HiltViewModel
class RegisterViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val firebaseAuth: FirebaseAuth
): ViewModel() {

    private val _register = MutableStateFlow<Resource<FirebaseUser>>(Resource.Unspecified())
    val register: Flow<Resource<FirebaseUser>> = _register

    fun createAccountWithEmailAndPassword(user: User, password: String){
        runBlocking {
            _register.emit(Resource.Loading())
        }
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, password)
            .addOnSuccessListener {
                it.user?.let {
                    _register.value = Resource.Success(it)
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener{
                _register.value = Resource.Error(it.message.toString())

            }
    }

}
```

Sealed class Resource.kt

```
package com.kirani.submee.util

sealed class Resource<T> (
    val data: T?=null,
    val message: String?=null
) {
    class Success<T>(data: T): Resource<T>(data)
    class Error<T>(message: String): Resource<T>(message = message)
    class Loading<T>: Resource<T>()
    class Unspecified<T> : Resource<T>()
}
```

SubmeeApplication.kt

```
package com.kirani.submee

import android.app.Application
import dagger.hilt.android.HiltAndroidApp

@HiltAndroidApp
class SubmeApplication: Application() {
}
```

AppModule.kt

```
package com.kirani.submee.di

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import dagger.Module
import dagger.Provides
import dagger.hilt.InstallIn
import dagger.hilt.components.SingletonComponent
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideFirebaseAuth() = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
}
```

data class User.kt

```
package com.kirani.submee.data

data class User(
    val firstName: String,
    val lastName: String,
    val email: String,
    var imagePath: String = ""
){
    constructor(): this("","","","")
}
```

build.gradle(Module:app)

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
    id("androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin")
    id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android")
}


android {
    namespace = "com.kirani.submee"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.kirani.submee"
        minSdk = 28
        targetSdk = 33
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    implementation("com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4")
    implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx:22.1.1")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    implementation("br.com.simplepass:loading-button-android:2.2.0")
    implementation("com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.13.0")
    implementation("de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0")
    implementation("io.github.vejei.viewpagerindicator:viewpagerindicator:1.0.0-alpha.1")
    implementation("com.shuhart.stepview:stepview:1.5.1")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.2")
    implementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.45")
    kapt("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:2.45")
    kapt("androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0")
}

kapt {
    correctErrorTypes = true
}
```

build gradle.kst (Project:Structure)

```
buildscript {
    dependencies{
        classpath("androidx.navigation.safeargs:androidx.navigation.safeargs.gradle.plugin:2.5.0")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15")
    }
}
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.1" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.8.10" apply false
    id("com.google.dagger.hilt.android") version "2.45" apply false
}
```

i've try anything till I forgot it

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.5.2"
```

inside Module grade dependency fixed the issue for me.

Also, make sure Dagger Hilt is in latest version.